# I don't know how to relate the position between 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I've been doing a program that check input orders and if it are into the menu will be stored in a list. Now I have to relate every order with their position on menu to relate also their correct price, and i don't know how to do it...
so we have menu[q,w,e,r,t]
with prices [1,2,3,4]
and if you put "t" the program have to know that it's price is 4, and not 0 or 1 due to the logical array index. 
Thanks to all and sorry for my poor english and code knowledge!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fase2_final {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] menu = { "chicken", "steak", "hamburger", "spaghettis", "pizza" };
        int[] price = { 10, 15, 20, 5, 12 };

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("We have " + menu[i] + " for " + price[i] + "€");

        }

        int option = 0;
        int yes = 1;
        int no = 0;

        System.out.println("What do you want to eat?");

        List<String> Order = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<Integer> TotalPrice = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            String userOrder = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

            boolean found = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {

                if (userOrder.equals(menu[j])) {
                    found = true;

                    Order.add(userOrder);

                    System.out.println(
                            "You ordered " + userOrder + "\nSomething more?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO      with 0");

                    option = keyboard.nextInt();

                    keyboard.nextLine();

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found) {
                System.out.println(
                        "We don't have this on menu!" + "\nDo you want to order another thing that we do have in menu?"
                                + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

                option = keyboard.nextInt();

                keyboard.nextLine();
            }

        } while (option == yes);

        //HOW CAN THE PROGRAM KNOWS THAT USERINPUTS SHOULD HAVE AN ORDER IN RELATION TO THE MENU AT THE SAME AS THE PRICES

        // Need to add the prices of the user's orders to a TotalPrice list
        //First we want to add just the prices related to the number of orders
        for (int w = 0; w < Order.size(); w++) {

            /* Then i don't know how to add just the correct prices of user's orders related to their positions in
                menu[i] and prices[i]*/
            for (int z = 0; z < Order.size(); z++) {
                TotalPrice.add(Order.indexOf(menu[z]));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Order finished! \nYour order have " + Order);

        System.out.println("The price is: " + TotalPrice);

        keyboard.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a simple class holding the variables for both the food and the price and use that class in your array and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Jaykooh you should use `Map` collection, which is provided by Java standard library. I posted an answer with the example below, please let me know if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to map menu items to prices. In that case you should use `Map<String, Double>`, since it is much more effective and convenient in comparison to array (in production you will never use arrays for that kind of tasks). String key - the name of the menu item, Double value - the price.

Declare it like that (By the way, I recommend to declare class objects using names that start from lowercase letters)

```
Map<String, Double> menu = new HashMap<>();
Double totalPrice = 0;
menu.put("chicken", 10); // The example of adding element to the map, add another items to menu like that
order.add("chicken");

for (int z = 0; z < Order.size(); z++)
    totalPrice += menu.get(order.get(z)); // + 5
```

Read more about the [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).